# sed regex command to output lines that end with html?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I need a sed regex command that will output every line in a while that ends with 'html', and does NOT start with 'a'.

Would my current code work?

```
sed 's/\[^a]\*\.\(html)\/p' text.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think this command will not work. But here is an good approach: try to write a command that prints every line that does not start with 'a', and another command that prints every line that ends with "html". Each of these is much easier than your current problem, and once you have both of them, you will find it easy to combine them.

Comment: Why is `sed` a requirement? Is this part of a larger `sed` program? Are you modifying existing code? More context will let us provide better answers.

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` command would be

```
sed -n '/^[^a].*html$/p'
```

But the canonical command to print matching lines is `grep`:

```
grep '^[^a].*html$'
```

Comment: What if the line contains just `html`?

Answer (score 0):

Sed just over complicates things...you can use grep to handle that easily!

```
egrep "^[^a].+\.html$" -f sourcefile > text.txt
//loads file from within the program egrep

egrep "^[^a].+\.html$" < sourcefile > text.txt
//Converts stdin file descriptor with the input redirect 
//to sourceFile for this stage of the` pipeline
```

are equivalent functionally.

or

```
pipe input |  xargs -n1 egrep "^[^a].+\.html$" > text.txt

//xargs  -n1 means take the stdin from the pipe and read it one line at a time in conjunction with the single command specified after any other xargs arguments
// ^ means from start of line, 
//. means any one character
//+ means the previous matched expression(which can be a 
//(pattern group)\1 or [r-ange], etc) one or more times
//\. means escape the single character match and match the period character

//$ means end of line(new line character)
//egrep is short for extended regular expression matches which are really
```

nice
(assuming you aren't using a pipe or cat, etc)

You can convert a newline delimited file into a single input line with this command:

```
cat file | tr -d '\n' ' '
//It converts all newlines into a space!
```

Anyway, get creative with simple utilities and you can do a lot:

xargs, grep, tr are a good combo that are easy to learn. Without the sedness of it all.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this with sed.  Do it with two different calls to grep

```
grep -v ^a file.txt | grep 'html$'
```

The first grep gets all the lines that do not start with "a", and sends the output from that into the second grep, which pulls out all the lines that end with "html".

Comment: What's the benefit of doing it with a pipe when it can be a single expression?

Comment: Because it can be easier to understand having things broken up into distinct pieces.